# Apache redirect page when , Rewrite condition user-agent is IE 8 and contains URI

Tags: apache

I have a requirement, when the client agent is not IE 8 and the requested URI contains a string the app should redirect to a page that shows the friendly warning message to the user to use IE8 to access the site and the below RewriteCondition is not working.

Appreciate if you could give some idea to resolve this, I tried various combinations, but none seems to be working.

```
 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s8`
 `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foobar.*`
 `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /foo/bar/warning.html`
```

Thanks for your valuable time,
Sudheer